# PHP Android No value for

Tags: php, android

I have one problem, when i´m going to run the app i receive one System.err: no value for anotacoes!

I think my problem is on php code. If someone help me i'll appreciate a lot your help.

(Sorry for my bad english ;) )

```
                   <?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();
$response1 = array();

 mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); // host, username, password...
    mysql_select_db("mobimapa"); // db name...

// check for post data

    $pid = $_GET['pid'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id_anotacao FROM processo_anotacoes WHERE id_processo = $pid");


        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            //$response["processo_anotacoes"] = array();

            $processo_anotacoes = array();
             while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                array_push($processo_anotacoes, $row["id_anotacao"]); 



           // $processo_anotacoes["id_anotacao"] = $row["id_anotacao"];
           // $processo_anotacoes["id_processo"] = $row["id_processo"];

            // success
            //$response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
           // $response["processo_anotacoes"] = array();


           }
          // echo json_encode($processo_anotacoes); 

 }
$ids = join(', ',$processo_anotacoes);

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anotacoes WHERE id_anotacao IN ($ids)");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) {

        $response1["anotacoes"] = array();

        // check for empty result
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

            //$result1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

            $anotacoes = array();
            $anotacoes["id_anotacao"] = $row1["id_anotacao"];
            $anotacoes["nome"] = $row1["nome"];
            $anotacoes["descricao"] = $row1["descricao"];

            // success
            $response1["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response1["anotacoes"] = array();

            array_push($response1["anotacoes"], $anotacoes);
        }
            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response1);   
    }

?>
```

> 08-12 17:09:03.308: D/All Products:(806):
>   {"success":1,"processo":[{"data":"2013-07-17","id_processo":"1","nome":"Processo
>   1","imagem":"Later"},{"data":"2013-08-04","id_processo":"2","nome":"Processo
>   2","imagem":"Later"}]} 08-12 17:09:03.518: I/Choreographer(806):
>   Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread. 08-12 17:09:29.238: D/Processo clicado(806): 2 08-12
>   17:09:29.838: D/Single Product Details(806):
>   {"product":[{"data":"2013-08-04","id_processo":"2","nome":"Processo
>   2","imagem":"Later"}],"success":1} 08-12 17:09:30.028: D/Anotacoes
>   Details(806):
>   **{"success":1,"anotacoes":[{"descricao":"teste","id_anotacao":"3","nome":"Anotacao
>   3"}]}**

Comment: where's the json_encode

Comment: here: // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response1);

Comment: maybe that happens android side when isset is false?

Comment: are you sure that `SELECT * FROM anotacoes WHERE id_anotacao = $response` does what you think it does?

Comment: @d'alar'cop look now, i have changed the code for one more simple, yes i´m sure the query is right.

Comment: where exactly do you see the error?.. on the android device?

Comment: @d'alar'cop on emulator logcat, i can print the result of first query, i don´t know what is wrong whith the second one :(

Comment: ah. well maybe you can post the logcat exception.. also you are putting "$response" in your second query and it is an array.. is that meant to be like that? (the query is expecting something to go with "id_anotacao")

Comment: I have added the logcat @d'alar'cop

Comment: what about my other question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is in the second query

Comment: Yes, an array with all id_anotacao(id_annotation) the first query found, to compare in other table to retrieve all information( second query). Me too, but i don´t understand where @d'alar'cop

Comment: But if there are multiple results then you might need to use WHILE loops to get each of them out one-at-a-time... and you may also need to use "where id_anotacao IN $<some array>". Yes I see the problem, I think.

Comment: Can you show me in code? @d'alar'cop

Comment: I will post it as an answer... it's not the complete code; but if you understand it, it will solve your problem.

Comment: de nada. I need to sleep now... 5am! All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the PHP variable being passed to the 2nd SQL query. This not the complete code; but if you understand it, it will solve your problem:

```
$anotacaos = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    array_push($anotacaos, $row["id_anotacao"]);  

$ids = join(',',$anotacaos);  
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anotacoes WHERE id_anotacao in ($ids)");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    //do something...
```

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)), instead of $result should not be $response ?! Continues to appear No value for anotacao. I'm doing anything wrong ? See the code now, i update it @d'alar'cop

Comment: no, that refers to the first SQL query - so that while statement gets each row at a time and performs some operations... you might consider using `$row[<column name referring to the ids of anotacaos>]`. Remember the point is not that this code, itself, "works", it's that you understand that you may need to loop over the result set of the 1st SQL query and then use that SQL I provided to get all the anotacaos. Let me know how you go.

Comment: i have updated the code, take a look. I think i´m close, but now in locgat i have a jsonparser error (string cannot be converted) and continues the no value for :( @d'alar'cop

Comment: ok. do you ever print out the php variables just to check they have the right stuff? also can you put the logcat stack trace?

Comment: look now i've added the logcat. i don´t need because the logcat tell me the values the json cant parse

Comment: I think you have not understood the usefulness of $ ids. that's for the 2nd SQL query. the first json_encode should not be using it also. try that then we'll see.

Comment: also printing the variables could be more useful in debugging to figure out _why_ it's providing a json that can't be parsed.

Comment: that is the code i have now and the logcat, i really need to get this done soon :|

Comment: ok. but the 2nd query still is not utilising $ids which was the whole point... I think you need to take the time to _really_ understand what the code provided above does. the part of your code dealing with the 2nd query is probably also not quite right which is why you will need to see what I'm trying to communicate to you.

Comment: What i have to do to use $ids on 2nd query ? Is in $row[id_anotacao] ?

Comment: yes. because it represents as a string the ids of the anotacaos (all of them). look at the code above.. an example is in the 2nd sql I put.

Comment: See the code now :) the only problem now is only give me the second annotation with id=3, and i have another annotation with id=1 :|

Comment: Take this out of the second WHILE loop - `// user node $response1["anotacoes"] = array();` - this is wiping your array clear every iteration. I'm glad we're getting closer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, all the best :D

Comment: Glad to help mate. God speed.